# Farseer engine built for MonoTouch?

Tags: farseer-physics-engine, monotouch

Does anyone know where I can find a version of the farseer physics engine compiled for MonoTouch, or do most people just download a windows version from codeplex and attempt to build their own solution?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also trying to include Farseer in a MonoTouch project, and I'm having loads of problems...

Answer (score 1):

Farseer is based on Box2D.XNA, and looking in their repository, I'm seeing what looks like managed C++ ([reference](http://box2dxna.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/62331#1429248)). I'm not familiar enough with managed C++ do know if it can be used to generate Mono-compatible .NET DLLs.

However, it looks like there's a native C# port of Box2D [here](http://code.google.com/p/box2dx/). Just run it through [MoMA](http://mono-framework.com/MoMA) and then try compiling it in MonoDevelop. I dunno if there's any compatibility scanner for MonoTouch, but last I read the main things you need to avoid are `Reflection.Emit` and unsafe code, and it's not likely those are used in this port of Box2D.